# saving loaded kernel modules

Tags: linux, centos, xen, kernel, kernel-modules

I did the following in command line:

```
modprobe ipt_LOG
modprobe ipt_multiport
modprobe ipt_state
modprobe ipt_limit
modprobe ipt_recent
modprobe ipt_owner
modprobe iptable_nat
modprobe tun/tap
modprobe iptable_nat
modprobe ipt_MASQUERADE
modprobe ipt_POSTROUTING
```

How do I get the kernel to use and bring those modules backup on a restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the [documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html):

```
# cat >/etc/rc.modules << EOF
modprobe ipt_LOG
modprobe ipt_multiport
modprobe ipt_state
modprobe ipt_limit
modprobe ipt_recent
modprobe ipt_owner
modprobe iptable_nat
modprobe tun/tap
modprobe iptable_nat
modprobe ipt_MASQUERADE
modprobe ipt_POSTROUTING
EOF
# chmod +x /etc/rc.modules
```